# Migration doesnt work with sails JS and postgresql db

Tags: postgresql, migration, sails.js

I just joined a project using SailsJS. I am trying to run a migration on the user model (I want to add a confirmed column boolean). I proceeded this way :

1) I modified the user model in models/User.js adding the confirmed attribute. Here's the model User.js :

```
attributes: {

 id: {
    type: 'int',
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  confirmed: {
    type: 'boolean',
    required: true,
    defaultsTo: false
  },
  facebook_id: {
    type: 'int'
  },
  email: {
   type: 'string',
   unique:true,
   required: true
  },
  password:{
   type: 'string'
   // ,
   // password: true
  },
  password_confirmation:{
   type:'string'
  },
  token: {
    type:'string',
    size: 2000
  },
  first_name: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },
  last_name: {
   type: 'string',
   required: true
  },
  full_name: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  poste: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  favorite_club: {
   type:'string'
  },
  picture: {
    type:'string',
    defaultsTo: 'https://wefoot.s3.amazonaws.com/default.svg'
  },
  birthday: {
    type: 'date'
  },
  mangoId: {
    type: 'integer'
  },
  telephone: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  password_reset_token:{
    type:'string'
  },
  last_seen:{   //Last opening of notif page
    type:'datetime'
  },
  pending_notif:{
    type:'int',
    defaultsTo: 0
  },
  nb_connection:{
    type:'int',
    defaultsTo: 0
  },
  last_lat:{
    type: 'float'
  },
  last_long:{
    type: 'float'
  },
```

2) In config/env/development.js I changed migrate: safe to migrate alter :

```
module.exports = {
  models: {
    connection: 'postgresLocal',
    migrate: 'alter'
  }
};
```

3) I ran sails lift and changed back development.js to migrate safe

But When I checked in Pgadmin, the new confirmed column is not showing up and I get this error in my logs

```
Unhandled rejection Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid
    at WLValidationError.WLError (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLError.js:26:15)
    at new WLValidationError (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLValidationError.js:20:28)
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/validate.js:46:43
    at allValidationsChecked (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/validations.js:210:5)
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:49:16
    at done (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:239:19)
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:40:16
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/validations.js:191:23
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:49:16
    at done (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:239:19)
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:40:16
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/validations.js:164:64
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:162:20
    at /Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:230:13
    at _arrayEach (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:81:9)
    at _each (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:72:13)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?